# How can I test if a string is made up from different characters only?

Tags: c#, string, character

I have a 5 character long string from `Console.Readline()` and I want to test if all 5 characters are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Distinct` method which will give you the distinct characters then just compare the count with the input `length`, if they are equal that means all chars are different.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

bool isDifferent = input.Distinct().Count() == input.Length;
```

Note you need `using System.Linq;` to use `Distinct` method.